# Session variable at master page is null in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

In my login page code behind:

After success of DB

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int intErr = 0;
        LoginDetails objLogDetails = new LoginDetails();
        objLogDetails.UserName = txtUsername.Value.ToString();
        objLogDetails.UserPassword = txtUserpassword.Value.ToString();

    if (Request.Form["rdoLogType"] != null)
        sType = Request.Form["rdoLogType"].ToString();
    else if (Request.Form["rdoLogType"] == null && txtUsername.Value.ToString().ToLower() == "admin")
        sType = "3";
    else
        sType = "0";
    try
    {
        if (Request.Form["rdoLogType"] == null)
        {
            intErr = 1;
            divErrMsg.InnerText = "Please Select Login type.";
            divErrMsg.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            int intLogId = 0;
            ServeAtDoorstepService objService = new ServeAtDoorstepService();
            if (sType == "1")
                intLogId = objService.LoginCustomer(objLogDetails);
            if (sType == "2")
                intLogId = objService.LoginVendor(objLogDetails);
            if (sType == "3")
                intLogId = objService.LoginCustomer(objLogDetails);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(intLogId.ToString().Trim()))
            {
                intErr = 1;
                divErrMsg.InnerText = "Invalid Loginname and Password! Please try again.";
                divErrMsg.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                Session.RemoveAll();

                Session.Add("LoginId", intLogId.ToString());
                Session.Add("LoginType", sType);

                if (chkAgree.Checked == true)
                {
                    HttpCookie cLoginId = new HttpCookie("LoginId", intLogId.ToString().Trim());
                    HttpCookie cLoginType = new HttpCookie("LoginType", sType);
                    cLoginId.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
                    cLoginType.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

                    Response.Cookies.Add(cLoginId);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cLoginType);

                    HttpCookie cLoginName = new HttpCookie("LoginName", txtUsername.Value.ToString().Trim());
                    HttpCookie cPassword = new HttpCookie("Password", txtUserpassword.Value.ToString().Trim());
                    cLoginName.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
                    cPassword.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

                    Response.Cookies.Add(cLoginName);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cPassword);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        divErrMsg.InnerText = ex.Message.ToString();
        intErr = 1;
    }

    if (intErr == 0 && Session["LoginType"].ToString() == "1")
        Response.Redirect("MyCustomerDash.aspx");
    else if (intErr == 0 && Session["LoginType"].ToString() == "2")
        Response.Redirect("MyVendorDash.aspx");
    else if (intErr == 0 && Session["LoginType"].ToString() == "3")
        Response.Redirect("MyAdminDash.aspx");
}
```

At my master page
this master page is common to all page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isShowHideControl = "0";
        lblWelcomeMsg.Visible = false;
        lblDashboard.Visible = false;

        if (Session["LoginId"] != null && (Session["LoginType"] != null && Session["LoginType"].ToString() == "3"))
        {
            lblWelcomeMsg.Visible = true;
            lblDashboard.Visible = true;
            isShowHideControl = "3"; // Admin
        }
        else if (Session["LoginId"] != null && (Session["LoginType"] != null && Session["LoginType"].ToString() == "2"))
        {
            lblWelcomeMsg.Visible = true;
            lblDashboard.Visible = true;
            isShowHideControl = "2"; // Vendor
        }
        else if (Session["LoginId"] != null && (Session["LoginType"] != null && Session["LoginType"].ToString() == "1"))
        {
            lblWelcomeMsg.Visible = true;
            lblDashboard.Visible = true;
            isShowHideControl = "1"; // Customer
        }
    }
```

But `LoginId` AND `LoginType` are always `null`.

Please help me to get the session value.

Comment: Did you try putting a break point and check the values after they are set/reset?

Comment: hi adarsh, in login page after adding session, it works....then it redirect to home page. in that master page session of id is null.what to do? help me

Comment: @user2879679 Can you post your full code for login page ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the event life cycle of master pages/web forms. I'm not entirely certain, but the mast page `Load` event may be firing after your `Click` event. See this page for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.ASPX

Answer (score 0):

See msdn [Session.Abandon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> When the Abandon method is called, the current Session object is queued for deletion but is not actually deleted until all of the script commands on the current page have been processed. This means that you can access variables stored in the Session object on the same page as the call to the Abandon method but not in any subsequent Web pages.
>   For example, in the following script, the third line prints the value Mary. This is because the Session object is not destroyed until the server has finished processing the script.

```
<% 
  Session.Abandon  
  Session("MyName") = "Mary" 
  Reponse.Write(Session("MyName")) 
%>
```

so in your sample you abandon session before redirect and on other pages it becomes unavailable. So for resolve try delete this line from your code in login page

```
Session.Abandon();
```